# MYSQL conversation list unique thread titles

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of messages with these columns

- id
- item_id
- user_from
- user_to
- message
- date_created

Message between any two users are about a given item_id. I want to create a conversation list for a user. So how do I get MYSQL to return a list of only the newest messages per item_id where the user can be either user_from or user_to.

Like, a "for each item_id where user_from = 10 or user_to = 10 return newest message".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I've been trying the whole day. TO no avail.

Comment: You should include your efforts in your post. The way your question is written (and your comment) doesn't show any effort at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the query that you are looking for, would be something like this:

```
SELECT `message` FROM `messages`
  WHERE `user_from` = "id"
  OR `user_to` = "id"
  GROUP BY `item_id`
  ORDER BY `date_created` DESC
```

Which means:

```
Get `message`
when `user_from` equals "id" or `user_to` equals "id"
but only once for every `item_id`
ordered by the latest date downwards
```

I hope this helps.